# How do I replace a string with dollar sign in sed?

Tags: sed

I want to replace this string:

```
export TODO_FILE="$TODO_DIR/todo.txt
```

with:

```
export TODO_FILE="$TODO_DIR/writing.txt"
```

in the file `~/.todo/config`. I've run it with:

```
sed -i 's/export TODO_FILE="$TODO_DIR/todo.txt"/export TODO_FILE="$TODO_DIR/writing.txt"/g' ~/.todo/config
```

But it says:

```
sed: -i may not be used with stdin
```

What should I do?

Comment: For completeness, include your version of `sed`; usually gotten from: `sed --version`

Comment: I can't get my sed version using those commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (Chris, you're very close):

```
sed -i '' 's|export TODO_FILE="$TODO_DIR/todo.txt"|export TODO_FILE="$TODO_DIR/writing.txt"|g' ~/.todo/config
```

Comment: According to the sed man page the suffix is optional (and I tested my version). Why does this work?

Comment: Someone will correct me, but I believe this behavior varies by version. At least in mine, `-i` is not the same as `-i ''`. The former implies that the option is "not set" (for the lack of a better word) and not allowed; the latter implies that it is zero-length, and allowed. `sed` version: GNU sed 4.2.1, on RHEL 6.5; does not appear to be optional. HTH.

Comment: I'm testing with the same version of sed on RHEL 6.4. Also, I believe the empty quotes should be attached to the -i option or be used with = in the long parameter. Clearly my answer obviously didn't solve his problem, but I don't think adding empty quotes is the answer, especially if they're passed as an individual parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is the dollar sign because it's inside single quotes. Assuming you're using bash, [strings inside single quotes are not variable expanded](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html).

One of your problems is that you have picked a separator character (the first character after the "s" command) that exists in your find/replace strings -- "/". This is being interpreted by sed differently than what you're expecting. You should pick a different character that doesn't appear in your find/replace strings, such as "|".

```
sed -i 's|export TODO_FILE="$TODO_DIR/todo.txt"|export TODO_FILE="$TODO_DIR/writing.txt"|g' ~/.todo/config
```

However, that doesn't explain your particular error message.

Maybe you're using the BSD version which [apparently treats the -i differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21243111/3549133)?

Comment: It still saying `sed: -i may not be used with stdin`. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Better first match the line and then just substitute the part

```
sed -i '/export TODO_FILE/ s/todo.txt/writing.txt/' ~/.todo/config
```

This becomes short when you have a path variable too long.

and as mentioned in the previous answer use some other separator when dealing with path.